# Issues regarding css and <input>

Tags: css, forms

Hello I have just learned HTML and CSS and lately I have been playing around and doing a lot of practice. I have noticed something when practicing coding search bars. I have noticed when I code the height of input buttons and the height of input search to be exactly the same, the search bar always ends up being taller. Why is that? If the search bar and button are 30px in height then you would think they would be the same height in the browser. Here is an example code of what I was doing. Thanks for your help every one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:#555;
}
.search_bar {height:30px;
 width:130px;
}
.button {height:30px;
 width:60px;
background-color:#777;
border:1px solid #444;
border-radius:4px;
color:#fff;
font-family:arial;
}
.button:hover {background-color:#0099ff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <input class="search_bar" type="text" /><input class="button" type="button" value="Search"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ohh... that's nothing! Your nightmare is just began

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because each browser comes with its own "user agent stylesheet".
It applies some rules to your page elements to display them "properly". That's why buttons, for instance, have a different look, depending on the browser.
You just have to overwrite those rules.

UPDATE: on Chrome, to check whether the browser has applied some predefined styles for your element, right click on it, inspect element, then on the right side, look for "user agent stylesheet" inside "styles" tab.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause form elements are relative to the OS and the predefined browser styling settings. And if you set `type="button"` ...it really becomes a pseudo `<button>` with all the default styles inherited from `button` elements.

**CSS3** finally goes to our favor by using

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pesaz/1/edit)**

<sub>Not that was not possible with CSS2 but with some tricks and hacks</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In your case the actual dimensions of the input box are 134*36 and that of the button are 60*30 (width*height).

Because the input types "text" and "button" are predefined, they have padding included in their style.

So if you want to know the actual height and width right click on the element in chrome and select "inspect element" in the menu.

Now you get to see your source code in a window at the bottom. Hover upon the source of the element in the window and you will see the actual height and width of your element.

So Adjust your width and height :)

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

All the browsers have default styles so each one will show each way.Just over-ride the browsers default styles of browsers and the font size also affect the height and width of the input buttons. And its not a right practice to fix the height of elements, its better to give padding instead. However too  much padding is also not a right practice.